# the cardinality $|\{A_{n}\}| = c$ where $c$ is the continuum

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I let $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ denote the set of all infinite sequences of real numbers. I can't seem to wrap my head around the idea that the cardinality $|\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}| = c$ where $c$ is the continuum. Since  $|\mathbb{R}| = c$, I have been trying to find a way to compare what I am trying to figure out with this but am getting nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: So many confusions in this question. $\mathbb R$ has the cardinality of the continuum. $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ has a larger cardinality. Also $\{A_n\}$ is very confused notation for the set of all sequences of real numbers.

Comment: It is better to use $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ to denote the set of sequences. There is less ambiguity there, and it may even suggest how a proof may proceed.

Comment: I made the appropriate fixes to this question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The cardinality of ${\mathbb R}$ is the same as the cardinality of $(0,1)$. So define an injection $(0,1)^{\mathbb N} \to (0,1)$ by first letting every even indexed digit of the target number be the corresponding digit of the first number, and then letting every remaining digit whose index is divisible by $3$ be the corresponding digit of the second number, and proceeding as such through all primes. All digits unassigned are zero.